# PHP unicode decode

Tags: php, unicode, decode

I have a PHP script that read string data from .xls file (via [PHP Excel Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)). But some special characters it returns in unicode encoded format. For example, instead of "é" returns "\xe9".

Is there any way, in PHP 5.2, how decode string with "\x??" characters to clasic UTF-8?

Thanks.

Comment: You should look into http://php.net/iconv.

Comment: I know iconv. But what I should put into first parameter? `$decoded = iconv(??, 'UTF-8', $string)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `utf8_encode()`

Here is an example: 
http://codepad.org/62STmyAl

Comment: It works, thank you! I tried utf8_decode(), and it doesn't work. But utf8_encode() does, I dont get it :-)